# Doing in line editing in VSCode using the Keyboard Only?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode we can create multiple cursors inside a single word or sentence by select alt or option (Mac) and then clicking where we want the additional cursors.

Is there a way to use the keyboard only to create the additional cursors (Instead of having to click)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a few commands to the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-multi-cursor-with-keyboard) v1.14.0 that allows to create and modify Multi Cursors with the keyboard.

- `selectby.addNewSelection` : Add a new selection at an offset (default: 1)
- `selectby.moveLastSelectionActive` : Modify (extend/reduce) the last selection by moving the Active position `offset` characters left/right (default: 1)
- `selectby.moveLastSelection` : Move the last selection number of characters left/right (default: 1)
- `selectby.removeCursorBelow` : remove the last selection

All 3 commands have 1 property, set in the `args` property of the key binding. If called from the Command Palette the value of `offset` is `1`.

You can define a set of key bindings to use these commands.

By using a custom context variable (extension [Extra Context](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.extra-context) v0.2.0) to set a mode, and use the `when` clause to determine if we use the default key binding for the arrow keys or our custom key bindings.

With the command `extra-context.toggleVariable` you can toggle the variable and thus the mode.

```json
  {
    "key": "alt+F5", // or some other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "extra-context.toggleVariable",
    "args": {"name": "multiCursorByKeyboard"}
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+right",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && extraContext:multiCursorByKeyboard",
    "command": "selectby.addNewSelection",
    "args": {"offset": 1}
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+right",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && extraContext:multiCursorByKeyboard",
    "command": "selectby.moveLastSelectionActive",
    "args": {"offset": 1}
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+left",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && extraContext:multiCursorByKeyboard",
    "command": "selectby.moveLastSelectionActive",
    "args": {"offset": -1}
  },
  {
    "key": "right",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && extraContext:multiCursorByKeyboard",
    "command": "selectby.moveLastSelection",
    "args": {"offset": 1}
  },
  {
    "key": "left",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && extraContext:multiCursorByKeyboard",
    "command": "selectby.moveLastSelection",
    "args": {"offset": -1}
  }
```

Comment: @ole I have it working with a context variable